# Sending file using ADODB.Stream to browser fails in Firefox and IE

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an application that is written with Classic ASP/VB Script. With this app I allow users to download files that are stored in a protected folder outside of root directory after several security checks.

```
|- wwwroot <- site root
|   |- App <- site files
|   |- ...
|- Protected
```

Here is my Codes:

```
fileid = Session("DownloadFileID")
if isNumeric(fileid) Then
    ' This function is equal to "SELECT str_filename FROM download WHERE id_download = fileid" and returns "N/A" if nothing found
    filename = GetTBLFieldValue ("download", "str_filename", "id_download", fileid, 0, 0)

    ' if download ID that were sent by session was correct then prompt download dialog
    if filename <> "N/A" Then
        Call DownloadFileForDownloadModules(filename)
    Else
        response.clear
        response.flush
        response.end
    End if
End if
```

**This is DownloadFileForDownloadModules Function:**

```
Function DownloadFileForDownloadModules(filename)
    filepath = server.mappath("../") & "/protected/"
    set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if Not fso.FileExists(filepath & filename) then
        Exit Function
    Else
        strAbsFile = filepath & filename
        Set objFile = fso.GetFile(strAbsFile)
        Response.Clear
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & objFile.Name
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Open
        '-- set as binary
        objStream.Type = 1
        Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
        '-- load into the stream the file
        objStream.LoadFromFile(strAbsFile)
        '-- send the stream in the response
        Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read)
        Response.End
        objStream.Close
        Set objStream = Nothing
        Set objFile = Nothing
    End if
End Function
```

The problem is:

1. I have a few complaints from clients who says they can't download files using Firefox and IE But they can download with Chrome. Even, I tried it with my IE and Firefox browsers and could download files without problem.
2. User can't download files by download managers such as IDM

Usually files are in PDF format but they are used to be different file format no matter what they are, they must be downloaded.

Comment: why Response.end bevor closing the stream?

Comment: @ulluoink I have to move it after closing stream object... is it necessary anyway (or I can remove it) ?

Comment: i do not think it is necessary. you could do a Response.flush or so to be sure that everything is sent. furthermore you should set the Content-Length to the length of the stream...

Comment: Yeah, I did it here `Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size`

Comment: yes but is the size of the file and the size of the stream the same? i dunno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an old app that does the same, below are the headers I use and can't recall having any probs. (Its ASP+JS but the idea is the same)

```
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer"); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report_" + (new Date()).valueOf() + sFullFilePath.substr(sFullFilePath.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase() + "\";");
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", objStream.Size);
```

You may as well also try to add the correct content-type by looking at the file extension;

```
  case ".xls": 
        ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
```